# Appium："message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched)"

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

```
import os, time, unittest
from appium import webdriver


PATH = lambda p:os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),p))

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'  
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.0.2' 
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'NX512J'  
desired_caps['app'] = PATH(r"D:\android\test\com.taobao.taobao_6.9.0_liqucn.com.apk")
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.taobao.taobao'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.taobao.tao.welcome.Welcome'

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps)
time.sleep(5)
```

error message as below
    info: [debug] Responding to client with error:{"status":33,"value": "message":"A new session could not be created.(Original error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched)","origValue":"UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched"},"sessionId":null}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Close appium and kill processes related to Appium. Open Appium again. It should be working properly.

Comment: It doesn't work when I closed 'adb.exe' and appium. I changed other mobile device, this issue no longer appears.

Answer (score 0):

Terminating the process abnormally while executing may results in this issue. In mobile/Virtual Device. close the Application First and then try the process.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use driver.quit every time in your teardown method and (--session-override",true ) in your desired capabilities.